# Using watchdog of python to monitoring afp shared folder from linux

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, watchdog, afp

I want linux machine(Raspberry pi) to monitor a shared folder by AFP(Apple file protocol, macbook is host).

I can mount shared folder by mount_afp, and installed watchdog python library to monitor a shared folder. The problem is that watchdog can monitor only modifications from linux machine itself.

If a monitoring folder has been modified by the host machine(Apple macbook) or other pc, linux machine couldn't find out the change. No logs came out.

After I tested the same watchdog python file in host machine(Apple macbook), I can get every logs of modifications by other machine.

Host machine can get every modifications of file or folder. But other machine(guest machine) can not monitor modifications of file from host or others.

Is it normal status of watchdog? Or is there any problem in account and permission?

Here is watchdog sample.

```
  import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


class Watcher:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = "/path/to/my/directory"

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print "Error"

        self.observer.join()


class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
            # Take any action here when a file is first created.
            print "Received created event - %s." % event.src_path

        elif event.event_type == 'modified':
            # Taken any action here when a file is modified.
            print "Received modified event - %s." % event.src_path


if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Watcher()
    w.run()
```

Comment: The watchdog can only monitor changes to the local file system. It is not notified by the OS and remote file system about changes.

Comment: @Klaus D Hi, is there any python library to monitor AFP shared folder?

Comment: The first question would be if the client is notified by the host. If not there won't be any library.

Answer (score 20):

For network mounts, the usual filesystem events don't always get emitted. In such cases, instead of using `Observer`, try using `PollingObserver` -- i.e., change from:

```
   self.observer = Observer()
```

to

```
   from watchdog.observers.polling import PollingObserver
   ...
   self.observer = PollingObserver()
```

There is also a `PollingObserverVFS` class you could experiment with.

Documentation: https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#module-watchdog.observers.polling

Comment: i tried from watchdog.observers import PollingObserver but import error.
i check the doc, and change to 
from watchdog.observers.polling import PollingObserver

and basically, its worked!!!

Comment: Code example has been updated to import from the correct module. Thanks everyone.