# creating watchfolder in Python, that performs certain operations

Tags: python, recursion, watchdog, python-watchdog

Currently I'm working on project which aims on creating watchfolder in Python that would perform certain operations. I read about watchdog library and I'm trying to implement it right now. My code is based on: [Using watchdog of python to monitoring afp shared folder from linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441623/using-watchdog-of-python-to-monitoring-afp-shared-folder-from-linux)

Here is structure of folders and subfolders on which operations have to be performed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c80Mu.jpg

The main folder `watchfolder` contain subfolders `subfolX` observed recursively. 
At the beginning, There is only watchfolder containing empty subfolders.
I have another program that moves special directories `VIDX` to specific subfolders. 
Now, three operations are done:

`settings_extractor()` is executed. This function open file `adi.xml` and basing on it create new file `settings.txt`.
`mediainfo_extractor()` is executed. This function returns specific information about the `VIDX.mp4` file. This information is then used to create `folderName` variable.
Basing on `folderName` the whole folder `VIDX` with contents (VIDX.mp4, settings.txt, adi.xml) is moved to another directory based on `folderName` variable.

Exemplary process of folder VID2 being moved to `subfol3` is here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIT04.jpg

However I encountered few problems. I don't know how should I properly set the operations order so it will result in desirable effect. I cannot understand 'recursiveness' completely, because program is performing some operations with clearing local variables. When I run program, it analyses `*.mp4` file first, creates `folderName` variable, however new event triggers memory clear and then script doesn't know where should it move files.

The basic watchfolder code is the same as in first link, however there is version on pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/Qh4mvgU1

Here is my code responsible for operations:

```
    if(event.event_type == 'created'):
        filename = path_leaf(event.src_path)            
        extension = os.path.splitext(event.src_path)[-1].lower()

        if filename == "adi.xml":
            adi_to_settings.settings_extractor(event.src_path)
            shouldMove = True

        if extension == ".mp4":
            #<PART OF CODE RESPONSIBLE FOR CREATING folderName>
            folderName = folderName.upper()
            folderThatWillBeMoved = str(Path(event.src_path).parent)


        if(len(os.listdir(r"C:\Users\user\WFS\watchfolder\subfol3\{}".format("folderThatWilLBeMoved))) >= 3 & shouldMove == True):
            moveAllDirsAndFilesinDir(r'C:\Users\user\WFS\watchfolder\{}'.format("folderThatWillBeMoved"),r'C:\Users\user\WFS\tempfolder\{}'.format(folderName))
            shouldMove = False
```

Summarizing, the main problem I have is to have control which operation on file will be performed first, or even better, which file is analysed first.
I tried to explain everything as brief and as clean as I could. I'd thankful for any hint bringing me closer to solution, how should I modify code in order to perform operations in a clean manner.

Comment: One problem you mention is: **'because program is performing some operations with clearing local variables'**.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570856/how-can-i-give-variables-to-the-event-handler) provides two methods to maintain variables with the simplest being to use global variables.

Comment: As a follow up to my comment, assuming your handler is a class then class variables could be used which would be better than globals in this case. [Class Variables](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3)